# How to get an instance of class in const expressions (decltype, templates ...)

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

How to get an instance of a class?

Everyone would answer: call its constructor

like
`class_name()`

Then what if the class has no default constructor?

---

I have a function accepting a byte buffer as argument:

```
template<typename BUFFER>
void fun(BUFFER& buf) {
```

I need to have some restrains on `BUFFER`, and I choose the newest `ranges`

```
template<std::ranges::range BUFFER>
void fun(BUFFER& buf) {
```

And this is a byte buffer, so the return type of `std::ranges::begin(buf)` should be `byte`

Then I added some requirments

```
template<std::ranges::range BUFFER>
    requires std::same_as<byte, decltype(*std::ranges::begin(BUFFER()))>
void fun(BUFFER& buf) {
```

This is no good because we don't know whether `BUFFER` has a default constructor

So, is there any solution better than the following code?

```
template<typename T>
struct instanceof_t {
    T value;
};

template<typename T>
using instanceof = instanceof_t<T>::value;

template<std::ranges::range BUFFER>
    requires std::same_as<byte, decltype(std::ranges::begin(instanceof<BUFFER>))>
void fun(BUFFER& buf) {
```

Comment: Aside: `decltype(*std::ranges::begin(BUFFER()))` might well be `byte &`, not `byte`. Perhaps you want `std::same_as<byte, std::ranges::range_value_t<BUFFER>>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already [`range_value_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iterator_t) which is used to obtain the value type of the iterator type of range type `R`, so in your case it should be

```
#include <ranges>

template<std::ranges::range BUFFER>
  requires std::same_as<std::byte, std::ranges::range_value_t<BUFFER>>
void fun(BUFFER& buf);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) can be used:

```
template<std::ranges::range BUFFER>
    requires std::same_as<byte, decltype(std::ranges::begin(std::declval<BUFFER>()))>
void fun(BUFFER& buf)
{
   // ...
}
```

but constraint might be really used:

```
template<std::ranges::range BUFFER>
requires (requires(BUFFER buf) {
    {std::ranges::begin(buf) } -> std::same_as<std::byte>;
})
void fun(BUFFER& buf)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think `std::ranges::begin` always accepts a rvalue.

Comment: And can I specify a type for `std::ranges::range`?

Comment: @aleck099: What do you mean by "specify a type" for it? It's a concept; the type the user provides is `BUFFER`.